# reason for "The name 'fieldname' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, epicorerp

I have a button and a numeric field in epicor invoice line detail form.When i enter some numeric value and press the button i want to copy the value i entered to the default unit price field in the form

```
private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
     String u=usrUnitPrc.Text;
     curUnitPrice.Text=u;
}
```

But on testing the code, it shows error
 The name **curUnitPrice** does not exist in the current context

** Compile Failed. **

Comment: 'curUnitPrice' is not declared in this method, it must be either declared at class-level as field/property or in this method to access it

Comment: it is in epicor erp invoice line.so in the form itself there is this curUnitPrice feild.But I can't able to declare it.Like when i declare it as String curUnitPrice=null; it shows error string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) #D.J

Comment: I am not familiar with epicorerp, is the form the same class as the one this method is from ?

Comment: yes the form is in the same class as the one this method is from. @D.J

Comment: can you post the code where this should be declared so it's possible to see the scope of that thing ?

Comment: the code is long (more than 601 lines).Still let me try

Comment: since code is too long it is not possible to paste here

Comment: Is there any epicor person,who can help me?

Comment: leave out the lines/methods that are not important for this issue, only where it is declared and where your method is so we geet the scope. the methods/elements in between don't matter much propably

Comment: I am new in epicor erp. I want to copy value from a field created by myself through customization in invoice form to default field in that form during a button click event.That is what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference curUnitPrice, you need to add the following line to the script:

```
EpiCurrencyEditor curUnitPrice = (EpiCurrencyEditor)csm.GetNativeControlReference("ENTER EPIGUID FROM curUnitPrice PROPERTIES");
```

If your control is not an EpiCurrencyEditor, just update the above to whatever the type happens to be.